# Pass javascript callback as java method argument

Tags: javascript, java, gwt

In my GWT application I have 3rd party react module
I need to pass success/failure callback from javascript to java where i will fill it with data

JS PART

```
function() {
        var reactCallback = {
            success: function() {
                console.log('success!');
            },
            error: function() {
                console.log('error!');
            }
        };
        window.reactRpcService(reactCallback);
    }
```

JAVA GWT PART

```
 public static native void reactRPCService(ReactRPCServiceAccessor reactRpc)/*-{
    $wnd.reactRpcService = function(callback){
        reactRpc.@com.myproject.ReactRPCServiceAccessor::dispatchRPCRequest(???)(callback);
    }
}-*/;


    private void dispatchRPCRequest(???) {

    }
```

Plan is to call java GWT RPC function normalize data and send it via callback back to `javascript`
I had idea to pass it areound in Java as `JavascriptObject` but dont know if it is a good way

Any ideas guys ?

Comment: Can you specify what you want to do exactly. What should be transferred? And what happens on the Java side? Isn't it possible to just call the Java function, do the business logic and depending on the result call a different JS method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually i found out that `JavascriptObject` according to javadocs can be `passed back into JSNI from Java becomes the original object, and can be accessed in JavaScript as expected.`

So in my native function i added signature like this

```
public static native void setupNativeRactRPCServiceCalls(ReactRPCServiceAccessor reactRpc)/*-{
    $wnd.reactRpcService = function(callback){
        reactRpc.@com.myproject.ReactRPCServiceAccessor::dispatchRPCRequest(Lcom/google/gwt/core/client/JavaScriptObject;)(callback);
    }
}-*/;

 private void dispatchRPCRequest(final JavaScriptObject callback ) {
...retrieve JSON data
}
```

and then after retrieving data from server i have passed it back to javascript

```
   public static native void reactDataRedirector(JavaScriptObject callbackObject, String jsonData)/*-{
        callbackObject.success(jsonData);
}-*/;
```